# Does $f(x)=x$ and $f(f(x))=x$ have exactly the same set of solutions when $f(x)$ is monotone?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, functions, inverse-function, monotone-functions

> Does $f(x)=x$ and $f(f(x))=x$ have exactly the same set of solutions when $f$ is a monotone function?

My try:

It is pretty obvious that every solution of $f(x)=x$ is also the solution of $f(f(x))=x$, since $f$ is a function. But how about the converse.

Case $I:$ When $f$ is Monotone Increasing

Let $x_0$ be the solution of $f(f(x))=x$ and let us assume that $x_0$ is not the solution of $f(x)=x$. Then WLOG, let us start with $f(x_0)<x_0$. So we have
$$f(x_0)<x_0 \Rightarrow f(f(x_0))<f(x_0)<x_0 \Rightarrow x_0<x_0$$ This is a contradiction. Thus every solution of $f(f(x))=x$ is also the solution of $f(x)=x$.

Case $II:$ But how about when $f$ is monotone decreasing? Any help?

Comment: Hint: for monotone decreasing, find nontrivial functions $f$ so that *every* $x$ is a solution to $f(f(x))=x$!

Comment: What about $f(x)=-x$, which is monotone decreasing?

Comment: Why is the question getting downvoted?

Comment: Just because I missed an easier counter example $f(x)=-x$, people are downvoting. Great and Kind hearted people here :)

Comment: There's no way to tell why you've received downvotes. It could be for other reasons.

Comment: Another counterexample could be $\frac1x$ for $x\gt0$ or $e^{1/\log(x)}$ for $0\le x\le1$.

Comment: It should be perhaps made more clear that the question is about set of $x$'s that solve given equations, not about set of functions $f$ (i.e. these are not functional equations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The statement is FALSE.**

Suppose $x_0$ is a solution, then we have $f(f(x_0))=x_0$. Let $y_0=f(x_0)$, hence $f(y_0)=x_0$

Case.(1) if $x_0=y_0$, then $x_0=y_0=f(x_0)$, and we are done.

Case.(2) if $x_0\neq y_0$, without loss of generality, let $x_0<y_0$, we have

$$x_0<y_0=f(x_0)$$

which implies $x_0$ is NOT a solution of $f(x)=x$. Hence, we can construct a counter-example. Let $$f(x)=\frac{15-x^3}7$$

which is a  monotonic function, and it is easy to check

$$f(f(1))=1,~~~~f(f(2))=2$$

but

$$f(1)=2,~~~~f(2)=1$$

Therefore, the statement in your OP is false!

Comment: why downvote. ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would guess that the downvote was because an easier counterexample, $f(x)=-x$, had been given earlier in a comment under the question.

Comment: I am not understanding why this is a counterexample. $f(f(x))=\frac{x^9-45x^6+675x^3+1770}{2401}$

Comment: @robjohn because if you plug in $x=1$, you get $f(f(1))=1$, so $x=1$ is a solution of $f(f(x))=x$. But $f(1)\neq 1$, hence $x=1$ is NOT a solution of $f(x)=x$.